# How to Split an Already Split String

Tags: c#, split

I have a code as below.

```
foreach (var item in betSlipwithoutStake)
{
    test1 = item.Text;
    splitText = test1.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (!test.Exists(str => str == splitText[0]))
        test.Add(splitText[0]);           
}
```

I'm getting values like `"Under 56.5 Points (+56.5)"`.

Now I want to split again with everything after `'('` for each items in the list so i will get a new list and can use it. How can I do that?

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to extract value inside parenthesis:

```
foreach (var item in betSlipwithoutStake)
    {
        test1 = item.Text;
        splitText = test1.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (!test.Exists(str => str == splitText[0]))
            if(splitText[0].Contains("("))
                test.Add(splitText[0].Split('(', ')')[1]);           
            else
                test.Add(splitText[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, above will split the all the strings all the time But i want to split again test only if '(' is available in the string . So can i modify it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you are after a solution without regular expressions, and that you have a `List<string>` test declared, you can follow up with a substring, with indexes (and some error handling):

```
foreach (var item in betSlipwithoutStake)
    {
        test1 = item.Text;
        splitText = test1.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (splitText.Length == 0)
            continue;

        string stringToCheck = splitText[0];
        int openParenIndex = stringToCheck.IndexOf('(');
        int closeParenIndex = stringToCheck.LastIndexOf(')');

        if (openParenIndex >=0 && closeParenIndex >= 0)
        {
            // get what's inside the outermost set of parens
            int length = closeParenIndex - openParenIndex + 1;
            stringToCheck = stringToCheck.Substring(openParenIndex, length);
        }

        if (!test.Exists(str => str == splitText[0]))
            test.Add(splitText[0]);           
    }
```

You can find out about all of the methods to use with strings [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).